# How effective are Razz Berries, quantitatively?

Tags: pokemon-go

I want to rationalize my Razz Berry usage.
The [official documentation](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/222049307-Glossary) is very vague:

> Razz Berries make the wild Pokémon *easier* to capture

Quantitatively, what game variables change?

- Do the Pokéballs become kind of "laser-guided" and hit even if not thrown perfectly?
- Does the Pokémon dodge Pokéballs less?
- Does the "temporary Pokéball escape" rate change? If yes, by what proportion?
- Does the "definitive Pokéball escape" rate change? (black smoke appears and fight ends)
- Are Razz Berries effective during the whole fight, or only until the next "temporary Pokéball escape", or only for a certain time?

[image: Razz Berry razzberry raspberry]

Comment: I think 2 and 3 are yes, 1 and 4 are no and 5 is only until it breaks out of a pokeball

Comment: @Aequitas: Would you mind creating an answer?

Answer (score 9):

It will increase the chance to keep the Pokémon inside the ball for one try. I'm not sure by what rate, since there is no data about this in the datamined file. If it gets out of the ball you'll need a new berry and if you miss the Pokémon the berry is not consumed. It'll be consumed once the Pokémon is in the ball.

The other values are most likely unaffected and there is no laser guide or crosshair/scope/etc. 

Since the effect is gone, after the Pokémon breaks out of the ball I don't believe the escape chance (end of fight) is affected. The other ones are based on your skills (aiming) and timing (dodging). The berry can't affect those.